# stop and start auto parallaxbackground in andengine

Tags: android

I am new in android development,i want to know How to start and stop auto parallax background ?
I have two buttons on screen,next and previous and i want to stop and start parallax on buttons click.
I am doing something like this:

```
    autoParallaxBackground = new AutoParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0, 5);

    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-10.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.backgroundAtlasRegion.getHeight(), this.backgroundAtlasRegion)));
    scene.setBackground(autoParallaxBackground);

    scene.setOnAreaTouchListener(new IOnAreaTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                ITouchArea pTouchArea, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                float pTouchAreaLocalY) 
        {

            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp())
            {
                autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - backgroundAtlasRegion.getHeight(), backgroundAtlasRegion)));

                if(pTouchArea == ForwardSprite)
                    if(pTouchArea == backSprite)
                    return true;
            }
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {

                if(pTouchArea == ForwardSprite)
                {
                    player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 3, 5, true);
                    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-10.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - backgroundAtlasRegion.getHeight(), backgroundAtlasRegion)));

                    //backgroundSprite.setPosition(backgroundSprite.getX()-5, backgroundSprite.getY());
                }
                if(pTouchArea == backSprite)
                {
                    player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 9, 11, true);
                    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(10.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - backgroundAtlasRegion.getHeight(), backgroundAtlasRegion)));

                    //backgroundSprite.setPosition(backgroundSprite.getX()+5, backgroundSprite.getY());
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately AndEngine doesn't provide function to start and stop autoParallaxBackground. However you can overcome it by adding few lines of code in your AutoParallaxBackground class from AndEngine. (Better way would be to extend that class in your own project)

```
package org.andengine.entity.scene.background;



/**
* (c) 2010 Nicolas Gramlich
* (c) 2011 Zynga Inc.
*
* @author Nicolas Gramlich
* @since 19:44:31 - 19.07.2010
*/
public class AutoParallaxBackground extends ParallaxBackground {
// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================

private float mParallaxChangePerSecond;
private boolean moving;

// ===========================================================
// Constructors
// ===========================================================

public AutoParallaxBackground(final float pRed, final float pGreen, final float pBlue, final float pParallaxChangePerSecond) {
super(pRed, pGreen, pBlue);
this.mParallaxChangePerSecond = pParallaxChangePerSecond;
}

// ===========================================================
// Getter & Setter
// ===========================================================

public void setParallaxChangePerSecond(final float pParallaxChangePerSecond) {
this.mParallaxChangePerSecond = pParallaxChangePerSecond;
}

// ===========================================================
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
// ===========================================================

@Override
public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
if(moving)
    this.mParallaxValue += this.mParallaxChangePerSecond * pSecondsElapsed;
}

// ===========================================================
// Methods
// ===========================================================
public void start(){
    this.moving = true;
}

public void stop(){
    this.moving = false;
}
// ===========================================================
// Inner and Anonymous Classes
// ===========================================================
}
```

The line:

```
this.mParallaxValue += this.mParallaxChangePerSecond * pSecondsElapsed;
```

is responsible for moving background. It's used in onUpdate method so you can easily block and unblock it by boolean flag. I've tried to start and stop every layer separatly but it's bigger and more complicated task.

Comment: you can mark my post as an answer and vote for it if you think I helped you. Thanks and have fun:)

Comment: hello Matueusz
can u please help me for player body jump in y axis?
please

Comment: is there a post already created with some details? Please give me a link and I will take a look:)